# Clear memory in loop with R

Tags: r

I'm running low with memory and speed as the loop proceeds. If I would place `gc()` in loop right after write.csv(), would that be correct and of any help?

Loop I have got:

```
for(i in seq_along(x) {
 ....
 ....
 write.csv(x, file=paste("C:/....",i,".csv",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `paste("C:/....", i, ".csv", sep=""))` and also `x[[i]]` instead of `x`. Consider providing some more info of what you are doing in the loop, are you creating temporary objects and then remove them?

Comment: No, actually I'm doing some scraping, that requires me to do it in steps. So the data is stored in steps. All works, just wondering if I could release some memory while in loop, after each `i` stored data.

Comment: I'm not sure why you couldn't just try this yourself and see. My guess, though, is that it won't help much, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector is called automatically when needed. Using `gc()` calls the garbage collector. I think, it makes only sense to use it if you remove objects in the loop. Then calling the garbage collector could help. Quoting from `?gc`:

> "[...] it can be useful to call ‘gc’ after a large object has been removed, as this may prompt R to return memory to the operating system."

Calling `gc()` can be time consuming. I did a little test to check that:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
lst <- rep(list(rnorm(10000)), 30)

res <- microbenchmark(
  for(i in seq_along(lst)) {
    write.csv(lst[[i]], file="delme.csv")
    gc()
  }, 
  for(i in seq(ll)) {
    write.csv(lst[[i]], file="delme.csv")
  })

levels(res$expr) <- c("with gc()","without gc()")
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

So it seems that calling `gc()` everytime is probably not a good idea. Of course it depends a lot on what you are doing in the loop.

Just a hunch: Garbage collection problems are not slowing your code down. You can probably optimize other parts of your code, e.g. using an `*ply` function instead of `for` loop can sometimes help.

Hope it helps,

alex